# Script to Push Files

Tags: ssh, bash, scripting, shell, scp

Script to Push Files
Hey Guys, Thanks for always being helpful, I have another issue that I need a little insight on how to fix.

See the below script I have and the error I get. I don't understand why it does that, am I not using the continue correctly?

```
#!/bin/bash -x
# @(#) File: filepush.sh
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Modication History:
# Date       Name                       Description
# 12/10/2014  Emmanuel Iroanya          Script to copy a file to all hosts listed in serverlist  file
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

source /opt/mgr/conf/file.conf
source /opt/mgr/conf/dest.conf
HOSTS=/opt/mgr/conf/$1serverlist.conf

echo "Are you sure you want to copy $file to the list of $1 servers"
echo "This may take a while!!"
echo -n "Enter 'y' or 'n':"
read CHOICE
case "$CHOICE" in
        y|yes|Yes) while read line
do
        ssh "$line" "mkdir -p $dest" && scp -r "$file" "$line:$dest"
done < $HOSTS
        continue ;;
     n|no|No) echo "Please try again later"

esac
```

And the Error:

```
./filepush: line 31: continue: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

Comment: Your continue statement outside of while done block

Comment: what do you suggest I do then? Please?

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `continue` command, it's not needed. Leave the `;;`, though -- that's how the end of a case is indicated.

The purpose of `continue` is to skip the remainder of a loop body, and start the next iteration. It has no meaning outside a loop, so you get this error. This isn't like C/Javascript/PHP -- you don't need a special statement at the end of a case to prevent falling through to the next case.

Comment: so when I take the     continue out but leave the     ;; it reads like 2 lines from the conf and thats it.

Comment: Use `ssh -n`. Otherwise, `ssh` reads all the rest of the standard input, and sends it to the server.

Comment: Have you looked at `pscp` and `prsync`, which allow you to do parallel `scp` and `rsync` commands? `rsync` will automatically create directories as necessary, so you don't need the separate `ssh` command.